# Why GIT commit displays my organization name and email rather than my name and email?

Tags: git, email, ubuntu, svn, github

My last commit was displayed with my organization name and email as committer on Github. After little research, I found many tweaks and tried these commands to change name & email in the last commit:

```
git -c user.name="my_name" -c user.email=my_email_address commit --amend --reset-author
git commit --amend --author "my_name <my_email_address>"
```

These commands worked perfectly but after merging the code, I just noticed that again my organization name is displayed with the last merge commit.

- Why my commits uses organization name & email rather than my name & email?
- Suggest me the best possible way to change name and email for the last merge and that may use the same (new) name/email for next commits.
- Is there any way to specify the name & email with every individual commit to end this confusion?

Comment: Follow the steps here : https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your config with:

```
git config --show-origin -l
```

That way, you can check *all* the config files which might contain your user.name and user.email

In your repo, make sure to set the right user and email you want

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git config user.name xxx
git config user.email xxx
```

If you don't any new commit (done after amending your old commits) would still be created with the old information.

Comment: Thanks @VonC but didn't get the last statement, seems there's some typo.

First command displayed error _unknown option `show-origin'_.

Comment: @Mambro you need Git 2.8 or more. Update Git: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170831/7490

Comment: Upgraded to 2.9.2 and now the command worked. Yes its showing my organization name & email in .gitconfig. Wouldn't changing username/email in this way will change for other git projects also as I've some official git projects placed besides this project in the root directory and I do commit there with official (organization's) username? Isn't there any way that I can define which username/email I wanna use for which project?

Comment: @Mambro if you want to define your user and email just for one git repo, see my answer: that local setting will apply *only* for that repo.

Comment: @Mambro also, interesting read: https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-email-address-private/

Comment: Thanks for that ^ interesting read as I was going to ask which email to display either public or private?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120089/discussion-between-mambro-and-vonc).